# Flyway throws exception in java EE application

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I decided to add in my application on JavaEE without frameworks Flyway support. I have configurated all in pom.xml, connections presents, but there is one problem - I get log from flyway that it can't find path to migrations.

```
09-Aug-2022 16:19:22.403 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations Unable to find path for sql migrations: db/migration
```

pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
          <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <configuration>
            <user>user228</user>
            <password>user228</password>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaee_task_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8</url>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It's my project structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGLMo.png)

Who faced with Flyway in javaEE project, help me please, what i have to fix?! I add project's github link - https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.

Answer (score 1):

[image: your repo]
please take a look: your folder is called db.migration while it should be 2 nested folders db / migration